# Access what property of the sender was passed into a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, foundation

This may be a ridiculous question, but I have a method like this in my view controller:

```
[self registerProperty:self.currentUser];
```

and in the implementation of `registerProperty:` I would like to get the string "currentUser".

I'm doing this because I want to observe the property of the view controller "currentUser", not the actual user object, so I can intercept the setter.

At the moment I'm checking the Objective-C runtime for a list of all properties of the view controller and checking if the value of the property equals the currentUser object:

```
-(void)registerProperty:(id)property 
{
    for (NSString *propertyName in [self allPropertiesOfClass:[property class]])
        if ([property isEqual:[self valueForKey:propertyName]])
             NSLog(@"The property passed into the method is %@", propertyName);
}
```

The problem with this is that I may have two properties that both contain the same user object, in which case either of them would pass that test. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the object whose property you want to observe and, separately, the property name as a string. That is, mirror (a subset of) the arguments of the KVO `-addObserver:...` method.

Comment: Ah yes, but the problem is I need to determine the name of the property, ie. I need a way to turn `self.arbitraryProperty` into the string `@"arbitraryProperty"`. I've seen this done before, for example in [libextobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTKeyPathCoding.h) but I don't understand at all how it works.

Comment: The caller should pass that in. The caller knows the property name. You should not use `[self registerProperty:self.currentUser]`, you should use something like `[self registerObject:self property:@"currentUser"]`.